# the rules behind treeshaking with an npm module and webpack

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

If I have an npm package that exports all its components from 1 index.js file:

```
export * from './components/A';
export * from './components/B';
```

Then if I have another package that consumes this package:

```
import {A} from 'my-package';
```

Will the contents of `components/B` be bundled even though it is never used in the consuming package?

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Doing this:

```
export * from './components/A';
export * from './components/B';
```

Is the same as doing:

```
export class A () ...
export class B () ...
```

If you just `import {A}...` you are telling webpack that what you only cares about is A.

By using named imports, webpack is capable of only bundling the content of A and not bundling B in the final output.

TL;TR: Always use named exports/imports if you want to have an optimised code at the end.